# Apache Redirect to /index.php - How to handle direct requests for /index.php

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, 301-redirect, rewritecond

I'm not 100% sure if this should be on server fault or stack overflow, though I'm leaning towards server fault.

Most PHP frameworks utilize Apache redirects to funnel all request to `/index.php` and then the framework handles the routing from there.  The issue I'm having is that our old site did not use this methodology and `/index.php` really was our home page.  Now that we released a new site, we want to redirect all direct requests to `/index.php` to `/home`.

I feel like I remember there being a switch or something in Apache which only performs a redirect if the current request is not the result of another 301 redirect.  I can't seem to find anything like this though.  Am I making this up?  If I am, is there some way to handle this situation?

I've stripped out my Apache configuration file to the absolute bare minimum to eliminate the chance of unknown redirects.  Here it is (though the domain name has been redacted):

```
##
# Some LoadModule includes
##

## Set the IP and ports for this server
Listen 10.0.15.246:80

## zend fastcgi
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddHandler fastcgi-script .php

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ## Set various vhost values
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/www.example.com/htdocs/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ##Set development environment
    SetEnv WEB_ROOT /www/www.example.com/htdocs/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

    RewriteEngine On

    ## My attempts to redirect /index.php to either / or /home
    #RewriteRule /index.php$ /home [R=301,NC,L]
    #RewriteRule /index.php$ / [R=301,NC,L]

    <Directory /www/www.example.com/htdocs/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have an `.htaccess` file located at `/htdocs/.htaccess` which is completely blank.
I also have an `.htaccess` file located at `/htdocs/public/.htaccess` which contains the following and nothing else:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

**What is currently happening:**

- When a user navigates to http://www.example.com/index.php they are
  getting a 404 error.
- When a user navigates to http://www.example.com or
  even http://www.example.com/home they wind up on my homepage.
- When a user navigates to `http://www.example.com/<anything else>` they either end up on my home page (when using the redirect to `/`) or an infinite redirect loop (when using the redirect to `/home`).

**What I want to change is:**

- When a user goes to http://example.com/index.php they end up on my homepage.
- When a user navigates to `http://www.example.com/<anything else>` it goes to the appropriate page (or a 404 error if it doesn't exist).

Comment: That last bit that you edited in is probably causing you all sorts of problems. You only need the ErrorDocument part of that; the rewrite is redundant (and broken).

Comment: Okay, I removed the rewrite, but I'm still getting the same behavior.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Quick question though.  It seems obvious to me, but I know I have to be missing something, but wouldn't this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]` redirect `/home` to `/index.php`?  And then wouldn't this line `RewriteRule ^/index.php$ /home [R=301,NC,L,QSA]` redirect `/index.php` to `/home` resulting in a loop?  Is it the fact that only one of them is a 301 redirect which should prevent the loop?

Comment: No, we talked about that one already. It rewrites, not redirects.

Comment: What's the distinction between a rewrite and a redirect?  Is it the 301 flag?

Comment: One tells the browser to redirect, the other doesn't. The rewrite you pointed out here loads `/index.php` but the URL in the browser is `/home` - and the URL passed to `/index.php` is _also_ `/home`.

Comment: Do you even _have_ an index.php file?! What sort of application is this? How is it getting loaded?

Comment: Yep, I have an index.php file.  It's a Zend Framework 2 application, so everything goes to the index.php file which bootstraps the applications and routes it to the appropriate controllers.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hi Michael, turns out my "solution" wasn't a solution after all.  As a troubleshooting process I've stripped my httpd.conf file to the absolute bare minimum to try to eliminate any chance of unknown redirects occurring.  I updated my question to include the httpd.conf file in it's entirety plus the `.htaccess` files in the path as well.  Maybe I was leaving something out which I didn't think was relevant, but was.  Do you see anything?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a flag/switch in Apache which prevented a redirect on an existing request which was previously redirected.

Instead, I looked to implementing a solution within the application itself.

For example, since my application was a Zend Framework 2 application, my solution was adding this to the /htdocs/public/index.php file:

```
if(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) === '/index.php'){
    header("Location: /home",TRUE,301);
    die();
}
```

It's not the cleanest of solutions.  But I only include the pieces of ZF2 I need rather than the whole package, so I don't have to worry about the file being overwritten due to an update.